# Android X86 and Grub

Tags: boot, android-x86

So I've installed Android X86 on my wetab tablet, using the corvus mod files found [here](https://corvusmod.wordpress.com/2012/01/24/android-ics-4-0-3-for-wetab-english/), but for some reason, my tablet now boots right into a grub 0.97 command line (I suspect it does this because there are no grub menu options configured). At this point, loading the kernel and initrd manually results in a frozen tablet, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get grub to boot android from the hard drive properly.

My only thought was to boot from a liveCD and take a look at the grub config files, but I cannot actually look at the hard drive in the tablet from the liveCD, since I don't have write permissions and thus cannot use the `mount` command.

If anyone has any idea as to what I could do to get grub to boot android from the hard drive, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks beforehand!

EDIT: Also, I used the installation instructions from [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2011/10/11/getting-started-on-android-for-x86-step-by-step-guide-on-setting-up-android-2223-for-x86-testing-environment-in-oracle-virtualbox), so I have sda1 and sda5 partitions, and I ran the installation with `DATA=sda1 SDCARD=sda5` options.